# Java error: method in the type Finch is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner)"

Tags: java, input

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
The method saySomething(String) in the type Finch is not applicable 
for the arguments (Scanner)
```

Code:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

String userInput;
System.out.println("Enter your two words: ");
userInput = user_input.next();

myf.saySomething(user_input);
```

I'm assuming the saySomething method doesn't accept scanner input, how do I convert the input to a string? Thanks

Comment: You're mixing up `userInput` (the string) and `user_input` (the Scanner). That's all. How about picking more descriptive, and sufficiently different, variable names?

Comment: What is the signature of method `saySomething`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of choosing similar variable names, which leads to confusing code like this:

your `saySomething(String)` method expects a String as a parameter, currently you are passing scanner.

```
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userInput=user_input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter your two words: ");
            myf.saySomething(userInput);
```

Name you variables something which you can diffrentiate from each other, and are meaningful.

```
Scanner userInput;
String  words;
```